# Python3: Dividing multiple values per key in one dictionary, by multiple values per key in another dictionary

Tags: python-3.7

I have 2 dictionaries. Each key in each dictionary has 4 values. I need to divide each value for each key in the first dictionary by the corresponding value for the corresponding key in the second dictionary and return the results to a new dictionary.
For example:

```
dict1 = {'key1' = [1, 2, 3, 4], 'key2' = [5, 6, 7, 8]}
dict2 = {'key1' = [2, 2, 2, 2], 'key2' = [3, 3, 3, 3]}
```

should result in:

```
result_dict = {'key1' = [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2], 'key2' = [1.67, 2, 2.33, 2.67]}
```

Some failed solutions I've tried:

```
def dict_div(dict1, dict2):
    result_dict = {}
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        if k in dict2:
            result_dict[k] = dict1/dict2[k]
    return result_dict
```

```
def dict_div(dict1, dict2):
    result_dict = {}
    return result_dict = {k: dict1[k] / dict2[k] for k in dict1 if k in dict2}
```

```
def dict_div(dict1, dict2):
    return numpy.divide(list(dict1.items()), list(dict2.items()))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You have filled out a box which prompted you to 'ask a question', which you seem to have forgotten. Please take the time to take the [tour], and read up on [ask]. One of the main things you'll learn from there is **show your effort**. We are willing to help you resolve your programming problems, we are not writing the code for you. Did you use your favourite search engine to search for this problem? Have you tried to code anything yourself? If so, please do [edit] the post to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are halfway there. Your first attempt had it almost all, except dividing the lists.

```
def dict_div(dict1, dict2):
    result_dict = {}
    for k, v in dict1.items():
        if k in dict2:
            result_dict[k] = numpy.divide(v, dict2[k])
    return result_dict
```

Numpy allows you to directly divide list items, otherwise you could have used something like:

```
def divide_lists(list1, list2):
    result = []
    for i, v in enumerate(list1)
        result.append(v/list2[i])
    return result
```

You can also write it with the style in your second attempt, which has fewer lines of code but might be difficult to understand at first:

```
def dict_div(dict1, dict2):
    return {k: numpy.divide(v, dict2[k]) for k, v in dict1.items() if k in dict2}
```